# Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Tags: php, codeigniter

Здравствуйте. Появилась такая проблема, на фреймворке *Code Igniter* появляется, время от времени, ошибка:

> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at c:\...\main.php:1)

Подскажите как исправить, ошибка появляется лишь иногда, пробелы проверил на разных кодировках - их нет. Ошибка также появляется после записи значений в класс *Session*.

Comment: http://cannot-modify-header-information.ru/

Comment: Ну вы хотя бы привели начало main.php

Comment: <?php
Начало

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/284578/  
Повтор вопроса

Answer (score 2):

Везде проверьте наличие невидимых символов и в конце ваших php файлов уберите закрывающий тег   ?> . Первым делом проделайте это с инклудными views.